# IE 9/10: Label redefined javascript error

Tags: cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I have a HTML DIV on my page and I am trying to assign the innerHTML value of this DIV using HTML string returned in an AJAX callback. When this happens IE9 and IE10 report the below error if "Display a notification about every script error" is turned ON in settings.

**SCRIPT1025: Label redefined**

I inspected the HTML returned in AJAX callback however it doesn't contain elements (all elements not just labels) with duplicate id or name attributes.

FireFox and Chrome browsers do not have this issue.

Any thoughts/anyone faced this issue before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Random guess: are you putting JSON in a script tag?

Comment: Please show us the ajax code and the server response, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks for your response. There is no JSON involved here. The AJAX callback result includes string HTML which is returned appropriately. The issue is only with innerHTML assignment

Comment: Can you make a demo then please with the document in which you are inserting, the script that does the assignment and the HTML string which you are assigning?

Comment: Found the issue. "javascript:" tag was repeated twice in event handler markup. This error in IE9/10 is misleading.

Comment: Nah, it's not. It says exactly what the problem is. `javascript:` is not a tag - it could be a pseudo-prototcol in href-links, but in plain code it's a [**label**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). And those must be unique.